# Worthy security related certifications for a software engineer

Tags: professional-education, software, certification

I am a software engineer with an interest in expanding my knowledge in the security field.

In addition to **security.stackexchange** and [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org), I am currently reading the book ["The web application hacker's handbook"](http://goo.gl/n5rrWV).

My question is; **based on your experience(s)** what are worthy security certifications for a software engineer to pursue? (certifications where you learn a good deal and that **could be**  in high demand by employers in the near future).

Comment: What certifications are you looking for specifically (ie CEH or writing secure programs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out SANS?  They are an excellent training and certification resource and have some software developer certifications.  Check out them out here: http://www.giac.org/certifications/software-security